# Why were there more than 10 things that she hates in Kat's poem?

Tags: analysis, 10-things-i-hate-about

In *10 Things I Hate About You*, Kat's poem titled '10 Things I Hate About You':

> I hate the way you talk to me
> And the way you cut your hair
> I hate the way you drive my car
> I hate it when you stare
>
> I hate your big dumb combat boots
> And the way you read my mind
> I hate you so much that it makes me sick
> It even makes me rhyme
>
> I hate the way you're always right
> I hate it when you lie
> I hate it when you make me laugh
> Even worse when you make me cry
>
> I hate the way you're not around
> And the fact that you didn't call
> But mostly I hate the way I don't hate you
> Not even close, not even a little bit, not even at all.

And here is the video:

But as someone can see, there were way more than 10 things in the poem. Why is that?

Comment: Well, since *"I hate you so much that it makes me sick, it even makes me rhyme"* doesn't count, and we'll say that *"I hate it when you make me laugh, even worse when you make me cry"* and *"I hate the way you're not around and the fact that you didn't call"* are each related and each count as 1, and that *"I hate the way I don't hate you"* is a paradox and cancels itself out... that's 10. :P

Comment: @Ankit Sharma I see only 10 "hate"s

Comment: @madmada things were more then the hate word used

Comment: I know, but I think it's perfectly reasonable to count every sentence after "hate" as one thing rather than break down some of them to 2 or 3 things .

Comment: @madmada But stuff like 'the way you talk to me' and 'the way you cut your hair' aren't related at all. How can we count them as one reason?

Comment: I'm not saying that we should and for me, when I look at the poem, I count 13 "things" not 10, but still, I don't think the way "the filmmakers" counted them that strange.

Comment: Two words: poetic licence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As this is based on Shakespeare's [*The Taming of the Shrew*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Taming_of_the_Shrew), Kat is likely reciting something akin to  a [Shakespearean sonnet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Shakespearean+sonnet), which is has this typical form...

> Composed of three quatrains and a terminal couplet in iambic pentameter with the rhyme pattern abab cdcd efef gg. Also called Elizabethan sonnet, English sonnet.

Now Kat's poem is a little longer and doesn't have the proper meter or rhyme scheme, but it's not too far off.  That being said, there are more than 10 things, because there are more than 10 lines.

I'd like to state that she actually only uses the word hate 10 times, hence the title of the film, but she actually uses it 11...

> I **hate** the way you talk to me
>
> I **hate** the way you drive my car
>
> I **hate** it when you stare
>
> I **hate** your big dumb combat boots
>
> I **hate** you so much that it makes me sick
>
> I **hate** the way you're always right
>
> I **hate** it when you lie
>
> I **hate** it when you make me laugh
>
> I **hate** the way you're not around
>
> But mostly I **hate** the way I don't **hate** you

Of course, the last time uses it, she negates it

> way I don't **hate** you

So, we'll say that doesn't count, and get to 10, and hence the title of the film.

Of course, in the end the film makers probably just preferred the sound of "10 Things", or were evoking David Letterman's Top 10 Lists, or were anticipating the arrival of click-bait listicles.

Comment: I hate the way you left out the hair thing

Comment: No, "And the way you cut your hair" does not have the word **hate** in it.  I have removed the other lines without it as well.

Comment: So you did. By now.

Comment: Id argue "I hate you so much it makes me sick" isn't a thing she hates about him.